# Can't update dispute evidence with Stripe API

Tags: node.js, stripe-connect, stripe.js

My application uses custom connected accounts. I'm having issues with updating dispute evidence via Stripe's API. Every time I try to update it says, "No such dispute: dp_XXXXXX".

[Stripe Docs: Update a dispute](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#update_dispute)

From what I understand I need to pass my stripe key, the dispute id, and any details I want to be updated as an `evidence` object.

I was having no luck passing data collected from my form to Stripe. So I tried just hardcoding the example request from Stripe's docs with several different dispute IDs that I'm getting back from the [Stripe disputes list endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#list_disputes). Again no luck here.

**Current setup with node:**

```
export async function update(data): Promise<any> {
  return await stripe.disputes.update(data.id, { evidence: data.evidence })
  .then((response) => {
    return {
      type: 'success',
      message: 'Dispute updated.'
    };
  }).catch((error) => {
    return {
      type: 'error',
      message: error.message,
      errors: error
    };
  });
 }
```

Using  example from docs:

```
export async function update(): Promise<any> {
    return await stripe.disputes.update(
    'dp_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    {
      evidence: {
        customer_name: 'Natalie Thomas',
        product_description: 'Comfortable cotton t-shirt'
      }
    }
   );
}
```

I've also just tried to use curl to test that it wasn't something I was doing wrong in Node.

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/disputes/dp_XXXXXXX \
-u sk_test_XXXXXX: \
-d evidence[customer_name]="Jacob Garcia" \
-d evidence[product_description]="Comfortable cotton t-shirt"
```

This is currently in development so I'm using all test keys/test environment. This is the first issue I've run into with the API.

These disputes are created using Stripe's test card `4000000000000259`.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

I've also tested retrieving a specific dispute and closing a specific dispute via curl. I get the same error for both of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my issue here.

When trying to update a **connected account** you also have to pass the connected account's ID into the API call. So for my original question, it would be:

```
stripe.disputes.update(
  data.id,
  { evidence: data.evidence },
  { stripe_account: data.accountId }
)
```

If it's not a connected account then you should be fine just passing the dispute ID.